# momentjs timezone delivers inconsistent hours

Tags: momentjs

I am using moment-timezone in my nodejs/express application on the server side. The problem ist that the `tz()` function returns inconsistent results and I don't understand why. Here's what I am doing:

```
items.forEach(function(item){
 moment(item.start.date).hour(5).minute(0).tz(Europe/Vienna).format()
})
```

(`item.start.date` comes in google `date` format(not `dateTime` format), like this: `2019-03-31`)
And it returns sometimes `+1` hour and sometimes `+2` hours like this:

```
2018-05-20T07:00:00+02:00
2018-08-15T07:00:00+02:00
2018-12-25T06:00:00+01:00
2018-12-26T06:00:00+01:00
2018-12-08T06:00:00+01:00
2019-01-01T06:00:00+01:00
2019-01-06T06:00:00+01:00
2018-05-21T07:00:00+02:00
2018-05-31T07:00:00+02:00
2018-11-01T06:00:00+01:00
2018-11-02T06:00:00+01:00
2018-12-02T06:00:00+01:00
2018-12-31T06:00:00+01:00
2018-10-26T07:00:00+02:00
2019-04-14T07:00:00+02:00
2019-04-22T07:00:00+02:00
2019-05-01T07:00:00+02:00
2019-04-19T07:00:00+02:00
2019-04-21T07:00:00+02:00
2018-10-28T06:00:00+01:00
2019-03-31T07:00:00+02:00
```

Your help is very much appreciated! Thanks a lot!

Comment: From the combinations of `+1` and `+2` above it appears to be due to Daylight Savings time.

Comment: You must be totally right! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `+1` and `+2` hours due to `Daylight Savings` time. To parse `DST` time you can check this link:

https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-ambiguous-inputs/

Just in case, to reconfirm if above date you are getting is in Daylight Saving format, you can use [isDST()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-daylight-saving-time/) function of momentjs. 
Below is one example:

```js
let isDaylightSaving = moment("2018-05-20T07:00:00+02:00").isDST();
console.log(isDaylightSaving);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that helps a lot!
The thing is that I need to set equal hours for all dates, without losing the dynamic DST timeZone offset...Do you have an idea how I can achieve this? I am trying this for hours now....thank you SO much!

Comment: of course! Thank you! The solution, by the way, was simple: hour() needs to be set after tz().